# CSS vertical-align: baseline with tables, forms and divs

Tags: html, css, forms, css-tables

I'm trying to build a form that contains inputs, textareas and block elements, each with a label. In order to get a flexible grid, I'm using a table. For a matching vertical alignment of the labels and the inputs/textarea I set `vertical-align: baseline;` which works fine for inputs and textareas. But not for divs ([see this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/55HfQ/2/)). The label for the div is consequently aligned at the bottom of the cell, but I want it on the top, i.e. the baseline should be on the top.

How can I achieve this without changing the contents of the div or having to differ between labels for inputs/textareas and divs? Is there any way to force an invisible baseline to be at the top of a table cell?

Maybe I'm not approaching the problem from the right side, any insight is appreciated.

Comment: I don't realy understand what you mean.  Baseline is at the bottom, that's what a baseline is.  Baselines are not at the top.

Comment: I know, thats why I would like to fake the baseline to be at the top.

Comment: So then don't use baseline, use top.  I fail to understand why you want to redefine things to mean somethign they're not.

Comment: After I slept over it, I'm finally able to understand that you are right. There is no simple way to avoid, it now looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/55HfQ/13/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the code below for your problem:

```
  td, label, textarea {
            vertical-align: top;
        }
```

Comment: But this produces an offset for labels on inputs and textareas.

Comment: This will create problem then...an offset will be,because of number of character inside label. One thing for your flexible grid, you can use div and your all element inside that in <p>. Hope it works...

Comment: I solved it by using `vertical-align: baseline;` on all `td`, and overwrite it with the element style `vertical-align: top;` for cells containing labels for divs.

Answer (score 0):

Your div must have at least one character (for example a *&nbsp;*).

---

For textareas, "vertical-align: baseline;" only works for Gecko.

As [developer.mozilla.org said](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea#Interaction_with_CSS),

> The HTML specification doesn't define where the baseline of a <textarea> is.

I found a workaround for that, but it changes the HTML.
I set vertical-align: text-top to the textarea, and to fix the gap caused by the height of the border-top and the padding top of the textarea, I set it a negative margin-top. And to  avoid having the textarea overlapping all elements above it, I put a div around the textarea with a padding-top to counterbalance the gap.

HTML:

```
<div class="textarea-wrapper"><textarea id="b">nice vertical alignment</textarea></div>
```

CSS:

```
.textarea-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 1px; /* - margin-top of textarea */
}
.textarea-wrapper textarea {
    vertical-align: text-top;
    margin-top: -1px; /* - (border-top-width + padding-top) */
}
```

I updated your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/55HfQ/21/).